# Android: Better control of when UI is updated

Tags: android, android-layout

My application performs a number of UI updates in close proximity, for example:

1. User takes a turn, and all gridview tiles are updated
2. AI takes a turn, and all gridview tiles are updated
3. AI takes another turn and all gridview tiles are updated

To get each of these updates to be visible to the user, I added each of these update tasks to a Handler on a non-UI thread. These Adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() tasks are then added to the UI thread's handler.

However, the only way I can get each update to be clearly visible is to specify a Thread.sleep() after I invoke the update. Even with this sleep, sometimes 2 & 3 are merged together and the user will only see 3.

As well as this, when 3 is performed sometimes it will take an extra split-second to update the entire grid. So rather than there being 3 clean updates of the grid, the user will seee 4.

As far as I can see, I am performing the Handler functionality as recommended by the programming guide. Therefore, I am wondering what else can I do to get better control of when the UI updates? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: It's a bit hard to really know what's going on, but my gut feeling is that you want to wait for your gridview to finish updating before doing the other steps. You can schedule commands on the griview's `post()` method, which will run until the gridview is finished updating (e.g. after a notifyDataSetChanged()).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this post method for a View. So, once this post() method returns false, I will know that it has finished updating?

Comment: It's more complex than that, [but better](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)). You declare a Runnable (probably as an anonymous class) and then that class' run() method will execute when it's done.

Comment: Ah OK, I think I got it. After I invoke my adapter's notifyDataSetChanged it will add a runnable to GridView.post(). So if I add one after notifyDataSetChanged, then I will know that the update has completed once this one runs...correct?

Comment: If you like so add that as an answer and I will accept it once I try this out, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered by dmon above.
Solution involved posting a Runnable to GridView.post() after I called notifyDataSetChanged in my adapter.
Game runs a little slower than before, but at least all UI operations render correctly.